# Check if image is visible (CoronaSDK)

Tags: android, image, lua, coronasdk

I'm new to coronaSDK and I am facing a problem now. I just wanted to know how to check if an image is visible or not.

```
local function buttonListener1( event )
    local lockedImage = display.newImage("locked.png")
    lockedImage.x = 240
    lockedImage.y = 170
    lockedImage.isVisible = true
    local myClosure = function() lockedImage.isVisible = false end
    timer.performWithDelay(1000,myClosure)
end
```

What I want to do is to check first if `lockedImage` is visible or not. If `true` then `lockedImage` won't appear again once triggered. Else, it will appear and perform `timer.performWithDelay(1000,myClosure)`. Any help is sincerely appreciated. Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It not clear what you are asking: do you want to extend buttonListener1 to do what you describe? but you create the lockedImage in that function so surely you mean something else. When is buttonListener1 called?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if myImage.isVisible then 
     ... do something ...
end
```

But to do what you describe the lockedImage must be created outside the buttonListener1, so the above technique implies something like:

```
local lockedImage = display.newImage("locked.png")
lockedImage.x = 240
lockedImage.y = 170
lockedImage.isVisible = false
lockedImage:addEventListener...

... presumably some listener might toggle lockedImage.isVisible 
    to true at some point ...

-- some button listener: 
local function buttonListener1( event )
    if lockedImage.isVisible == false then
        -- show for one second
        lockedImage.isVisible = true 
        local myClosure = function() lockedImage.isVisible = false end
        timer.performWithDelay(1000, myClosure)
    end
end
```